# Unable to fire the click event in React Component

Tags: reactjs

Not sure what is wrong here, a very simple component that has click event attached. I have bind the 'this' in the constructor but still the click event would not fire.

```
export default class ClickComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
    }

    clickHandler() {
        console.log('Clicked !!!');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.clickHandler}>Add</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I believe this is all we need to have click event in React. Any help would be great.

Comment: If this is a new project created using `create-react-app` I think there's a bug in the recent version that has issues binding `this` in class-based components. If you search the github it's an easy issue to find. Found it [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10598). Still open, some people seem to still have some issue.

Comment: @DrewReese, I did not use create-react-app. I wired things up manually.

Comment: Ok, I don't see any issue with this code. Can you provide a *running* codesandbox (or similar) that reproduces the issue that we can inspect live?

Comment: Try to change clickHandler() to clickHandler = () => {  console.log('Clicked');  },

Comment: @littleanimboy Are you passing this component as a prop to any other component that comes from a library or something ?

Comment: try changing the console.log to alert... some times console.log will be overriden in parent...

Comment: @DrewReese, I tried to create a Sandbox code and worked perfectly. I thinks there is some issue in my local that code fails silently without any err.

Comment: Check the console's logging level, ensure you aren't filtering "info" or non-warning/non-error logs.